# Where can I aquire global wind (speed and direction) data?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Where can I acquire global wind (speed and direction) data? 
Preferably in some kind of GIS format and free of charge.

Cheers

Comment: Do you require real-time or past information?

Answer (score 2):

windyty is non-commercial and in the menu tells you what open source libraries are used to create it. including noaa data
https://www.windyty.com/?36.797,-76.177,4

noaa climatic data (this is u.s. only, but i know they have it globally)
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/societal-impacts/wind/

so if you dig around between the two you should find what you need.
the bonus from windyty is they also show you how you can display it

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need a forecast or observations, assuming both, my recommendation will be.

1. Most common global forecast containing wind data is **GFS by NCEP**.
   You can see if it contains required wind variables and play with data values [via free API at Planet OS Datahub](http://data.planetos.com/datasets/noaa_gfs_global_sflux_0.12d:gfs-global-weather-forecast-by-ncep-near-surface-parameters).
2. For observational, historical global wind data, I'd suggest looking into *CCMP Wind Vector Analysis Product V2.0* which is modelled from satellite and weather stations. It contains U & V vectors, so both, direction and scalar speed can be calculated. You can look at the dataset details at [original source](http://www.remss.com/measurements/ccmp) or inspect values [via free API at Planet OS Datahub](http://data.planetos.com/datasets/rss_ccmp_winds_v2:ccmp-wind-vector-analysis-product-v20).

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the [Global Wind Atlas](https://globalwindatlas.info/) by the DTU Energy and the World Bank Group. They have global data in GIS format, free of charge. Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Although [sailwx](http://www.sailwx.info/wxobs/stationreport.phtml?wxid=OIBJ) primarily purpose is to display maritime information, you may find some wind-related data (speed and direction) from weather stations in easy-to-crawl tables. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

A few of my colleagues in the MELODIES project (www.melodiesproject.eu) are using open wind data from various European sources. I just asked them for their recommendations:

1. There are the brand new shiny [Copernicus data sets](http://marine.copernicus.eu/)
2. You can also get **global** re-analysis data from the [European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasting](http://www.ecmwf.int/en/research/climate-reanalysis/browse-reanalysis-datasets). The data come in GRIB/netCDF format which should be well-supported for conversion.